# Removing duplicate values in R

Tags: r, duplicates, tidyverse

I would like to remove duplicate values from a dataset. I do not want to delete entire rows though, I would like to remove the value and leave it blank.

Below is an example of the data frame I am using.

```
  A01 A02 A03 A032 A01_CD A02_CD A03_CD A032_CD
1   4.9  NA  NA   NA    4.9     NA     NA      NA
2   4.9  NA  NA   NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
5   4.8  NA  NA   NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
9   4.8  NA  NA   NA    4.8     NA     NA      NA
16  4.7  NA  NA   NA    4.8     NA     NA      NA
18  4.7  NA  NA   NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
31  5.0  NA  NA   NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
```

This is the outcome I would like to achieve.

```
  A01 A02 A03 A032 A01_CD A02_CD A03_CD A032_CD
1   4.9  NA  NA   NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
2   4.9  NA  NA   NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
5   4.8  NA  NA   NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
9   4.8  NA  NA   NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
16  4.7  NA  NA   NA    4.8     NA     NA      NA
18  4.7  NA  NA   NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
31  5.0  NA  NA   NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
```

I have been using: No_Duplicates = dataset11 %>% distinct(A01, A02, A03, A032, A01_CD, A02_CD, A03_CD, A032_CD, .keep_all = TRUE)
But this deletes entire rows and I do not want that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` row-wise to turn duplicate values to `NA`

```
df[] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), NA)))
```

Also with `purrr::pmap_df`

```
purrr::pmap_df(df, ~{x <- c(...);replace(x, duplicated(x), NA)})

# A tibble: 7 x 8
#    A01   A02   A03  A032 A01_CD A02_CD A03_CD A032_CD
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#1   4.9    NA    NA    NA   NA       NA     NA      NA
#2   4.9    NA    NA    NA   NA       NA     NA      NA
#3   4.8    NA    NA    NA   NA       NA     NA      NA
#4   4.8    NA    NA    NA   NA       NA     NA      NA
#5   4.7    NA    NA    NA    4.8     NA     NA      NA
#6   4.7    NA    NA    NA   NA       NA     NA      NA
#7   5      NA    NA    NA   NA       NA     NA      NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R option

```
do.call(rbind,Map(function(x) replace(x,duplicated(x),NA),asplit(df,1)))
```

which gives

```
   A01 A02 A03 A032 A01_CD A02_CD A03_CD A032_CD
1  4.9  NA  NA   NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
2  4.9  NA  NA   NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
5  4.8  NA  NA   NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
9  4.8  NA  NA   NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
16 4.7  NA  NA   NA    4.8     NA     NA      NA
18 4.7  NA  NA   NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
31 5.0  NA  NA   NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(A01 = c(4.9, 4.9, 4.8, 4.8, 4.7, 4.7, 5), A02 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), A03 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
    A032 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), A01_CD = c(4.9, NA,
    NA, 4.8, 4.8, NA, NA), A02_CD = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), A03_CD = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), A032_CD = c(NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1",
"2", "5", "9", "16", "18", "31"))
```

Comment: `t(apply(df, 1L, function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), NA)))` will also work if they are all the same type as here.

Comment: @BenjaminChristoffersen Yes, exactly. That is what is shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63917415/12158757

Comment: Oh, sorry. I figured that might be faster but I have not tested it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `transpose()` from `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
foo <- function(.) replace(., duplicated(.), NA)
df[] <- transpose(lapply(transpose(df), foo))
df
```

Reproducible data:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  A01 = c(4.9, 4.9, 4.8, 4.8, 4.7, 4.7, 5),
  A02 = NA_real_, A03 = NA_real_, A032 = NA_real_,
  A01_CD = c(4.9, NA, NA, 4.8, 4.8, NA, NA),
  A02_CD = NA_real_, A03_CD = NA_real_, A032_CD = NA_real_
)
```